# GDAX signature example

Tags: base64, sha256, hmac

I just can’t seem to get the signature right and I think some sample data would help me diagnose the problem. Can anyone offer some sample data to help me “calibrate” and make sure my code is functioning properly?

1. prehash string
2. base64-encoded secret
3. base64-decoded secret
4. sha256 HMAC using the base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string
5. base64-encoded result

I am working in VBA.  Any additional tips/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is a bit broad.  Are you having a specific problem that can be addressed?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no one will provide you with the sample data you are requesting as that would mean they in a sense would be sharing their own private passphrase, API key and secret with you.

1. go to gdax.com and click on API.
2. Generate copy the generated passphrase (do not lose this)
3. Go thru remaining steps to generate API key and secret (do not lose this)
4. Use the API reference to create authentication requests (signing, HMAC, Etc.)
5. Consider an easier way to interact with REST API than VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Sample data for "calibration" of your software can use the following inputs:

> timestamp: 1517266319.000
>
> method: GET
>
> requestpath: /accounts
>
> secret: D1/0wNj3wsKg8XcTs4KCfZUVzsHXIOW7w38Moj+YximHA5VQS7zAG47bgNSNGIGtFtYQ0vei2JiSPvX3JkBsA==

The correct signature for the above inputs is:

> jQxycBtZQKEWUZjtIaFnD1zoUDQebGeHmoIW3KHvmtg=

This is confirmed by both the NodeJS and Python code samples.